# Exceeded filesize limit with importing revolution slider from other website

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Im trying to import an existing revolution slider template from one site to another.
Whenever im importing the .zip file i get the error below

"Exceeded filesize limit"

I have already tried increasing all limits in the .htaccess file:

php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value max_input_vars 1800
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

But it is still not working.
Im stuk at the moment.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

locate the file PHP.INI
wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\bin
modify this lines
max_input_vars = 2500
memory_limit = 128M

you can increase the value according to your wish